Shader goes black on scene change
I am new to working with shaders, and I have a terrain generation system made from Sebastian Lague's procedural terrain tutorials:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFt_AvWsXl0eBW2EiBtl_sxmDtSgZBxB3
My problem is with the terrain shader(Builtin-Render Pipeline), if I start the game (In the editor) on the scene with the terrain generation everything works fine, But if I start in or switch to a different scene then switch back to the scene with the terrain, the terrain shader renders as black. I've tried to find an answer everywhere but just can't find anything.
Shader Code:
Shader "Custom/Terrain" {
    Properties {
        testTexture("Texture", 2D) = "white"{}
        testScale("Scale", Float) = 1

    }
    SubShader {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 200
        
        CGPROGRAM
        // Physically based Standard lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
        #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows

        // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
        #pragma target 3.0

        const static int maxLayerCount = 8;
        const static float epsilon = 1E-4;

        int layerCount;
        float3 baseColours[maxLayerCount];
        float baseStartHeights[maxLayerCount];
        float baseBlends[maxLayerCount];
        float baseColourStrength[maxLayerCount];
        float baseTextureScales[maxLayerCount];

        float minHeight;
        float maxHeight;

        sampler2D testTexture;
        float testScale;

        UNITY_DECLARE_TEX2DARRAY(baseTextures);

        struct Input {
            float3 worldPos;
            float3 worldNormal;
        };

        float inverseLerp(float a, float b, float value) {
            return saturate((value-a)/(b-a));
        }

        float3 triplanar(float3 worldPos, float scale, float3 blendAxes, int textureIndex) {
            float3 scaledWorldPos = worldPos / scale;
            float3 xProjection = UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2DARRAY(baseTextures, float3(scaledWorldPos.y, scaledWorldPos.z, textureIndex)) * blendAxes.x;
            float3 yProjection = UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2DARRAY(baseTextures, float3(scaledWorldPos.x, scaledWorldPos.z, textureIndex)) * blendAxes.y;
            float3 zProjection = UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2DARRAY(baseTextures, float3(scaledWorldPos.x, scaledWorldPos.y, textureIndex)) * blendAxes.z;
            return xProjection + yProjection + zProjection;
        }

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
            float heightPercent = inverseLerp(minHeight,maxHeight, IN.worldPos.y);
            float3 blendAxes = abs(IN.worldNormal);
            blendAxes /= blendAxes.x + blendAxes.y + blendAxes.z;

            for (int i = 0; i < layerCount; i ++) {
                float drawStrength = inverseLerp(-baseBlends[i]/2 - epsilon, baseBlends[i]/2, heightPercent - baseStartHeights[i]);

                float3 baseColour = baseColours[i] * baseColourStrength[i];
                float3 textureColour = triplanar(IN.worldPos, baseTextureScales[i], blendAxes, i) * (1-baseColourStrength[i]);

                o.Albedo = o.Albedo * (1-drawStrength) + (baseColour+textureColour) * drawStrength;
            }

        
        }


        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}

code that fills shader parameters:
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;

[CreateAssetMenu()]
public class TextureData : UpdatableData {

    const int textureSize = 512;
    const TextureFormat textureFormat = TextureFormat.RGB565;

    public Layer[] layers;

    float savedMinHeight;
    float savedMaxHeight;

    public void ApplyToMaterial(Material material) {
        
        material.SetInt ("layerCount", layers.Length);
        material.SetColorArray ("baseColours", layers.Select(x => x.tint).ToArray());
        material.SetFloatArray ("baseStartHeights", layers.Select(x => x.startHeight).ToArray());
        material.SetFloatArray ("baseBlends", layers.Select(x => x.blendStrength).ToArray());
        material.SetFloatArray ("baseColourStrength", layers.Select(x => x.tintStrength).ToArray());
        material.SetFloatArray ("baseTextureScales", layers.Select(x => x.textureScale).ToArray());
        Texture2DArray texturesArray = GenerateTextureArray (layers.Select (x => x.texture).ToArray ());
        material.SetTexture ("baseTextures", texturesArray);

        UpdateMeshHeights (material, savedMinHeight, savedMaxHeight);
    }

    public void UpdateMeshHeights(Material material, float minHeight, float maxHeight) {
        savedMinHeight = minHeight;
        savedMaxHeight = maxHeight;

        material.SetFloat ("minHeight", minHeight);
        material.SetFloat ("maxHeight", maxHeight);
    }

    Texture2DArray GenerateTextureArray(Texture2D[] textures) {
        Texture2DArray textureArray = new Texture2DArray (textureSize, textureSize, textures.Length, textureFormat, true);
        for (int i = 0; i < textures.Length; i++) {
            textureArray.SetPixels (textures [i].GetPixels (), i);
        }
        textureArray.Apply ();
        return textureArray;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Layer {
        public Texture2D texture;
        public Color tint;
        [Range(0,1)]
        public float tintStrength;
        [Range(0,1)]
        public float startHeight;
        [Range(0,1)]
        public float blendStrength;
        public float textureScale;
    }
        
     
}

I don't know anything about shaders, so I just tried to change a couple of things, I changed them back after it did not work.
I expected the terrain to have colors based on the y-level, but it was all black.
